# Reading data from the Firebase real time database, wondering what to put in place of the UserId

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read data from my Firebase Realtime database. I am wondering if there is a specific User ID am I supposed to replace userId with, as can be seen in this code.

`get(child(dbRef,"modules/"${userId})).then((snapshot) => { }`

I genuinely would really love some help on this

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

When you have the app initialized and the user is logged in you can use `getAuth` to get the current user.

```js
import { FirebaseOptions, initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig: FirebaseOptions = {
  ...
};

if (!getApps().length) {
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

const app = getApp();
const auth = getAuth();
const userid = auth.currentUser.uid
```